# Using ArcPy to get layer symbology?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, layers, symbology

Since ArcGIS 10 comes with the ArcPy package, I'm wondering it is possible to use ArcPy functions to get Symbology (i.e color, width...) of a layer?

Answer (score 17):

For ArcGIS 10.0, if you can make use of a read-only approach, the following code sample reveals the field (and joined table) that forms the basis for the symbology of a layer.  It exports a temporary msd(a zip containing xml files) and loads the specific attributes into an object.  These classes might be extended to gain access to additional layer attributes.

```py
import zipfile
from arcpy import mapping
import os
from xml.dom.minidom import parse


class LayerExtras(object):
    """ An object to hold attributes loaded from xml inside the msd."""

    name = ""
    symbologyFieldName = ""


class MxdExtras(dict):
    """ Exposes extra MXD details by raiding an exported msd

        Treat this object as a dictionary with layer name as the key and a custom object
        with desired attributes as the value.
        You must have write access to MXD directory (creates temporary msd file).
        Only layers in the first dataframe are accessed.

    """    

    LYR_NAME_NODE = "Name"
    LYR_SYMBOL_NODE = "Symbolizer"
    LYR_FIELD_NODE = "Field"
    MSD_SUFFIX = "_MxdExtrasTemp.msd"
    MXD_SUFFIX = ".mxd"
    EXCLUDED_FILE_NAMES = ["DocumentInfo.xml", "layers/layers.xml"]
    mxdPath = ""

    def __init__(self, mxdPath):

        self.loadMxdPath(mxdPath)


    def loadMxdPath(self, mxdPath):
        """ Load mxd from file path """

        self.mxdPath = mxdPath.lower()
        mxd = mapping.MapDocument(self.mxdPath)

        msdPath = self.mxdPath.replace(self.MXD_SUFFIX, self.MSD_SUFFIX) 

        # Delete temporary msd if it exists
        if os.path.exists(msdPath):
            os.remove(msdPath)

        mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxd,msdPath)

        zz = zipfile.ZipFile(msdPath)

        for fileName in (fileName for fileName in zz.namelist() if not fileName in self.EXCLUDED_FILE_NAMES):
            dom = parse(zz.open(fileName))
            name, lyr = self.loadMsdLayerDom(dom)
            self[name] = lyr
        del zz
        os.remove(msdPath)

    def loadMsdLayerDom(self, dom):
        """ Load dom created from xml file inside the msd. """

        lyr = LayerExtras()  

        # Layer name
        lyr.name = dom.getElementsByTagName(self.LYR_NAME_NODE)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

        # Symbology field name
        symbologyElement = dom.getElementsByTagName(self.LYR_SYMBOL_NODE)[0]
        lyr.symbologyFieldName = symbologyElement.getElementsByTagName(self.LYR_FIELD_NODE)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

        return lyr.name, lyr


############
# Test

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mxdPath = r"c:\temp\AmphibianSpeciesRichnessAverageOf30mCells.mxd"

    mxde = MxdExtras(mxdPath)

    for lyr in mxde.itervalues():
        print "Layer Name: ", lyr.name 
        print "Layer Symbology Field Name: ", lyr.symbologyFieldName
        print
```

Example output of test:

```
Layer Name:  Amphibian Species Richness Average of 30m Cells
Layer Symbology Field Name:  biodiversity.AmphAve
```

Comment: Use a context manager for that zip file: `with zipfile.ZipFile(msdPath) as zz:`.

Comment: @MichaelJackson In your code, I have only replaced the mxd path. But I got an error at the ` lyr.symbologyFieldName = symbologyElement.getElementsByTagName(self.LYR_FIELD_NODE)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` line, sayying `list index out of range`.  this is because the `symbologyElement.getElementsByTagName(self.LYR_FIELD_NODE)` is empty. But why is it empty? I assumed that this is an alternative to the lyr.symbology method, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @panda This is an old answer.  Are you using version higher than 10.0?  If yes, see answer below about the symbology property of the layer object.

Comment: @MichaelJackson I use the symbology property but it seems it's not supported in all the cases, like when the layer uses more than one field for symbology. I need to get the names of the fields used, but I can't find a method.

Answer (score 10):

ArcPy looks to let you change the symbology, but only with [existing .lyr files](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00150000000s000000.htm), and not specify the symbols directly in your code based on my reading of the module.

Answer (score 7):

In ArcGIS 10.1 and newer there is direct access to the symbology via the [symbology property of the layer object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm#P_GUID-A1071A05-599A-4662-8354-4F676BA87878).

For ArcGIS 10.0 the mentioned workarounds did work for me.

Comment: unfortunately, the symbology of a layer is read-only (according to the fifth instance of "symbology" on [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000t000000),  as well as the one you cited).

Comment: However  _"Not all layer symbology class types are supported; for those that are not, the keyword OTHER is returned."_. Unsupported types include Raster Unique Values, Unique Values Many Fields, and Dot Density. This is still true in ArcGIS 10.5. If you're lucky enough to have a supported SymbologyType see script in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184133/accessing-layer-properties-with-arcpy