# ArcObjects: How to get a reference to layer in a java add in

Tags: arcobjects, java, add-in, arcgis-desktop

I am trying to implement a java add-in version of this solution:
[unique value symbolize layers from a lookup table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1611/unique-value-symbolize-layers-from-a-lookup-table).
At the same time I want to start coding in Java for the ArcGIS Desktop, so I am rewriting the sample *Custom renderer*, which is implemented as a property page in the layers -> properties -> Symbology -> Custom Renderer tab.
The above solution uses

```
IGeoFeatureLayer gfLayer = mxDoc.FocusMap.get_Layer(0) as IGeoFeatureLayer;    gfLayer.Renderer = (IFeatureRenderer)UvrItem.MakeUVR(@"Filepath");
```

Now, ArcMap surely knows the featurelayer, when editing its properties. But the Custom renderer is just handed a featureCursor. So I try to get a reference to GeoFeatureLayer
through the activeView like this:

```
    public boolean canRender(IFeatureClass fc, IDisplay display) throws IOException, AutomationException {

    try {
        HookHelper hookhelper = new HookHelper();
        IActiveView activeView = hookhelper.getActiveView();
        System.out.println("The Layer Name Is:   " + activeView.getFocusMap().getLayer(0).getName());   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + e.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
    if (fc.getShapeType() == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But I get Error Message: Null.

If anyone more experienced than me knows the best way to do this in java,
I would very much appreciate some advice.

Best Regards, Marianne B. Wiese

Comment: You've posted 2 snippets...which one throws error? Are you trying to use the second snippet for ArcGIS Desktop customization? If yes, you'd be getting problems cause Hookhelper is designed for ArcEngine and not Desktop. Read [this](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/componenthelp/esricontrols/hookhelper.htm)

Comment: The second snippet throws the error. Thanks for pointing out, that it is not for extending a desktop application.

Comment: Is there another way to obtain reference to actual layer from layers _custom_ property page?

Comment: What version are you on?  Did you try following [this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#//00010000046v000000)?