# How to access and modify properties of one single layer with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, layers

**In General**

I have to access and modify a specific property, e.g. `data source`, of one specific layer with `arcpy`. I know the name of the mxd-file, the dataframe and the layer. How can I access, for modification, this one single layer directly without the common `for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(...)` loop as suggested in other answers (e.g. in the [manual](https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm) or in [case 18433](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184133/accessing-layer-properties-with-arcpy))? I also don't manage to use [UpdateLayer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatelayer.htm): this command allocates properties by fetching them from another layer, however, I don't have another layer which could deliver the desired properties.

**Example**

```
import arcpy, os
workspace_mxd = r"L:\project\home"
workspace_old = r"L:\project\scenario1"
workspace_new = r"L:\project\scenario2"
mxdfile = os.path.join(workspace_mxd,'mxd','map.mxd')
datasource = os.path.join(workspace_old,'data','points.shp')
layername = 'village'
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace_mxd
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdfile)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
for dataframe in df:
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, layername, dataframe):
        lyrDatasource = lyr.dataSource if lyr.supports('dataSource') else 'N/A'
        if lyrDatasource == datasource:
            lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(workspace_old,workspace_new,False)
mxd.save()
del mxd
```

By this approach, the property `data source` is modified for one specific layer. The approach looks inflated for this purpose. E.g. the two `for` loops are, in the specific case, for one dataframe and one layer only. Isn't there a shortcut to do what is finally done with `lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(workspace_old,workspace_new,False)`?

Comment: Please include a code snippet that illustrates precisely what you have tried instead of just alluding to your attempts.

Comment: If you know how to iterate a layer list, you know how to isolate a layer.

Answer (score 1):

When iterating over the layers in your loop, check layer.name for a match to the target layer name, and\or use the filter parameter in ListLayers to reduce the list to layers matching your target layer name. If adding a filter to ListLayers, you can operate on the first layer returned if you are confident there is only one possible match.